# How to list all files in directory/subdirectory without path name CMD?

Tags: windows, batch-file, directory, cmd, dir

I Have a directory containing many subdirectories. Within these subdirectories are loads of .asf, .jpg, & .txt files. I would like to list all *.asf files within the directory and subdirectory but without the pathname.

So basically I want to do the dir /s command but not display the full pathname. Is there anyway to do this.

Answer (score 12):

Very late but may be useful to someone.
I guess he is asking for this one line command

**`forfiles /m *.asf /s >d:\Hitendra.Txt`**

here as you all know after this **`(>)`** I'm saving result in D drive of my computer with
a file name Hitendra.Txt

Comment: Thanks, this is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 6):

Check:

```
FORFILES /S /C "CMD /C ECHO @relpath"
```

Answer (score 5):

try this on the cmd shell prompt:

```
for /r %a in (*.asf) do @echo %~tza %~nxa
```

only the name:

```
for /r %a in (*.asf) do @echo %~nxa
```

Comment: Than you so much. It really helped me. :)

Answer (score 4):

You can try

```
dir /s | findstr .asf
```

Edit: I think this would help. This is my `test.bat`

```
@echo off
for /f "usebackq TOKENS=*" %%i in (`dir /s /b *.txt`) do echo %%~nxi
pause
```

`/f usebackq` says that whatever inside backquotes are executed as dos command

`TOKENS=*` parses file names with spaces also.

`echo %%~nxi` - `n` lists out only the file names and `x` lists out only the extension. Combining both displays file name and extension.

Edit:
`usebackq` is not necessary instead single quote can be used.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However this still lists the complete path of each file, I would like to just extract the 'filename.asf'.

Comment: `usebackq` means the quoting scheme has changed, **not** a command follows. See `for /?`  for help. You don't need `usebackq`  here.